# Codekit: Any way to reorder projects?

Tags: codekit

Working with codekit at the office, my project list is getting somewhat extensive. We have two or three network drives that we do work on, and whenever one isn't connected I get scattered 'X'es in my project list - as a compulsive organizer, it sends my skin crawling.

Is there any way to automatically sort projects, even just by name?

I considered removing and re-adding projects in the order I want them to appear, but then I'd have to remove a good chunk of the list to put a new project in proper order (and I open a new project sometimes once a week). Any insight is appreciated - thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Coming in 2.0. (I would know; I write the app.)

Comment: Fantastic - thanks Bryan! When are you planning on rolling that out? ;)